# Two list comparison in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1=[[['B', 10], 1], [['C', 15], 1], [['F', 30], 1]]
list2=[[['G', 20], 2], [['D', 25], 1]]
```

Now `[['B', 10], 1]]` in `list1` matches with `[['D', 25], 1]]` in `list2` because they have equal second element (`[1]` and `[1]`, first match).

I want to say `['B', 10]` and `['D', 25]` is modified and `[['C', 15], 1]` and `[['F', 30], 1]` is deleted from `list1` also `[['G', 20], 2]` is added into `list2`.

Can someone help me here? I've tried sets and iteration of lists and comparing they both doesn't work.

Note: This is not a homework, its just I am wondering how list works.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I want to say ['B', 10] and ['D', 25] is modified` - and `['G', 20], 2]` is already in `list2` so not sure what you want to do there.

Comment: You're using some confusing terminology, can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: What if one list is `[[['B', 10], 1], [['C', 15], 2]]` and the other is `[[['C', 15], 2], [['B', 10], 1]]`?

Comment: @tobias_k: Then I will say bot list are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
list1=[[['B', 10], 1], [['C', 15], 1], [['F', 30], 1]]
list2=[[['G', 20], 2], [['D', 25], 1]]

list2_iter = iter(list2)
for item1 in list1:
    in_list2 = False
    for item2 in list2_iter:
        if item1[1] == item2[1]:
            print "Match" if item1 == item2 else "Modified", item1, item2
            in_list2 = True
            break
        else:
            print "Inserted", item2
    if not in_list2:
        print "Deleted", item1
```

Note that the inner loop for `list2` is using an iterator, so it does not start from the beginning of `list2` each time, but from the last element it stopped in the previous iteration of the outer loop. Everything else is rather straightforward.

Output:

```
Inserted [['G', 20], 2]
Modified [['B', 10], 1] [['D', 25], 1]
Deleted [['C', 15], 1]
Deleted [['F', 30], 1]
```

Note that this will not always find the best match, as it will only do one pass through both, `list1` and `list2`. For a more complete algorithm, take a look at [Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm) and [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

---

*Update:* I just realized how this problem is in fact virtually the same as finding the [minimum edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of two strings, for which I just happened to have some code lying around. After some generalization:

```
import operator

def diff(s1, s2, match=operator.eq, neutral="*", subst=2):
    """s1, s2: the two strings or lists to match
    match: function to determine whether two elements match up
    neutral: 'neutral' element for padding
    subst: substitution costs
    """
    s1, s2 = neutral + s1, neutral + s2

    # calculate edit distance / sequence match with DP
    A = [[0] * len(s2) for i in range(len(s1))]
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for k in range(len(s2)):
            if min(i, k) == 0:
                A[i][k] = max(i, k)
            else:
                diag = 0 if match(s1[i], s2[k]) else subst
                A[i][k] = min(A[i-1][k-1] + diag,
                              A[i  ][k-1] + 1,
                              A[i-1][k  ] + 1)

    # reconstruct path
    path, i, k = [], len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1
    while i or k:
        if A[i][k] == A[i-1][k] + 1:
            path, i = [-1] + path, i-1
        elif A[i][k] == A[i][k-1] + 1:
            path, k = [1] + path, k-1
        else:
            path, i, k = [0] + path, i-1, k-1

    return A[len(s1)-1][len(s2)-1], path


def print_match(list1, list2, path):
    i1, i2 = iter(list1), iter(list2)
    for p in path:
        if p == -1: print "DEL %20r"      %  next(i1)
        if p ==  0: print "EQ  %20r %20r" % (next(i1), next(i2))
        if p == +1: print "INS %41r"      %            next(i2)

# with strings
word1, word2 = "INTENTION", "EXECUTION"
x, path = diff(word1, word2)
print_match(word1, word2, path)

# with your lists of lists
list1 = [[['B', 10], 1], [['C', 15], 1], [['F', 30], 1]]
list2 = [[['G', 20], 2], [['D', 25], 1]]
x, path = diff(list1, list2, match=lambda x, y: x[1] == y[1], neutral=[[None, -1]])
print_match(list1, list2, path)
```

Note that the resulting match can *still* be different from what you expect, since often there are many equally optimal ways to match the elements, but it should be optimal nonetheless.

Comment: @ tobias:Thanks that's what I wanted to do.

Comment: Now when I am using 
  
    list1=[[['B', 10], 2], [['C', 15], 1]]
    list2=[[['B', 10], 1], [['C', 15], 1]]

Output is:

    Added [['B', 10], 1]
    Added [['C', 15], 1]
    Deleted [['B', 10], 2]
    Deleted [['C', 15], 1]

According to me it should be:

     Modified: ['C', 15] ['B', 10]
     Deleted ['B', 10]
     Added: ['B', 10]

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't work for every case

Comment: Yes it doesn't solve the purpose as if using different examples its not working

Comment: The post you suggested seems to be very complex :(

Comment: What changes should we do in this algorithm to do best match, as I ma looking for that algorithm implemented in python @tobias_k

Comment: @user2592659 The algorithm is indeed rather complex, that's why I can't work out all the details for you. Why don't you try to implement it and report back with a new question in case you have problems?

Comment: Thank you so much for the links and advice, I will try to implement it. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user2592659 Just realized that I had something very similar to that algorithm lying around somewhere. See my update.

Comment: Thank you so much But what if case is modified?

Comment: @user2592659 Do you mean "if the case of a letter is modified", or "in case an entry is modified, but not equal"? In the first case, pass a different `match` function. In the latter case, you'll have to check this in a second pass (given that your `match` function matches modified entries), or in the `print_match` function. Think about how `diff` for files works: Lines that are different, but seem to match, are aligned, and then there's probably a second pass of `diff`/`minimum edit distance` applied to that line.

Comment: Now [['B', 10], 1]] in list1 matches with [['D', 25], 1]] in list2 because they have equal second element ([1] and [1], first match).  I was taking abut this case.

I want to say ['B', 10] and ['D', 25] is modified

Comment: @user2592659 As I said, you'll have to check this e.g. in the `print_match` function. Just check whether the element is equal or just "matches", i.e. only the second part is equal, so it is modified.

Comment: :Thanks also what is the impostance of these:- match=lambda x, y: x[1] == y[1], neutral=[[None, -1]])

Comment: @user2592659 As I said, I've used a minimum-edit-distance algorithm and modified it for this problem. Those parameters are for defining when two elements are to be considered "equal", or "matching", and what to use as some sort of neutral filling element.

Comment: @Tobiac: I check it like this: But its' not working                                                                            ´code´  for p in path:
         if p == -1: print "Deleted:",next(i1)
  
         if p ==  0: EqualOrModified(next(i1), next(i2))

         if p == +1: print "Added:",next(i2)

  #if p ==  0 and next(i1)[0]==next(i2)[0]:
  # print "Equal:",(next(i1), next(i2))
  #else:
   #print "Modified:",(next(i1), next(i2))

def EqualOrModified(next1, next2):

 if next1[0]==next2[0]:
  print "Equal:",next1, next2
 else:
  print "Modified:",next1, next2

Comment: @user2592659 What example are you using and what output do you expect? Please add a more complex example to your original question, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: I did some changes and it worked!! Thanks once again!

Comment: I want to make some changes again in my question, Can you help me in this, should I post a new question and tagg you or can I mail you personally

Comment: @user2592659 Since this question has long been closed (and thus no one else than me will have a look at it, much less be able to post an answer to it) I _strongly_ suggest posting a new question.